# LinkedIn Get Token returns HTTP 1.1 400 - Bad Request Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, oauth, linkedin-api

I'm currently having trouble fetching the LinkedIn Token.

I'm currently following the [developers documentation in order to get through authentication](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication).

I'm also using [this sample](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/code-samples) as a base code

However, after I get through the authorization process, in which I get the auth-code, the process of getting a token for an user fails, with a Bad Request Error (400)

Here's a modified code from the sample page 
(**Note:** the commented parts we're previous attemps I've made, before moving to cURL)

```
 public function getAccessToken() {
        $params = array('grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'client_id' => API_KEY,
            'client_secret' => API_SECRET,
            'code' => $_GET['code'],
            'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI.'/linkedin/auth',
        );


        // Access Token request
        $url = urldecode('https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?'.http_build_query($params));
        //header("Content-length: ".strlen($url));
        // Tell streams to make a POST request


        echo $url;

        /*$context = stream_context_create(
            array('http' =>
            array('method' => 'POST',
            )
            )
        );*/

        /*$context  = stream_context_create(
                        array('http' =>
                            array('method'  => 'POST',
                                  'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                  'content' => http_build_query($params))
                        )
                    );

        // Retrieve access token information
        $response = file_get_contents($url, FALSE, $context);*/


        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        $token = json_decode($response);

        echo json_decode($response);

        // Store access token and expiration time
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $token->access_token; // guard this!
        $_SESSION['expires_in']   = $token->expires_in; // relative time (in seconds)
        $_SESSION['expires_at']   = time() + $_SESSION['expires_in']; // absolute time

        return true;
}
```

Forgot to mention that, the `echo $url;` part, outputs an url that, when manually inserted in the browser, **generates a valid user token**

Comment: Did you try to `urlencode` the code and redirect_uri parameters?

Comment: @Yan Yes I did. The result was the same. Bad Request when getting the response, but, manually inserting the URL in the browser works as expected, being that a JSON response with the expiration timestamp and the access token.

Comment: Did you trying sending it as a `GET` instead of `POST`?

Comment: @Yan Actually, I assumed LinkedIn would only reply to my request only if I made a POST request, not a GET on. However, it works perfectly with a get request! Please submit a formal answer so I can accept it! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the request to work, it must be sent in `GET` instead of `POST`.

Remove this line:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
```